# Is there a way to optimize a simple SQL request with a big database

Tags: sql, sqlite, unity-game-engine, optimization, query-optimization

I'm using SQLITE with Unity3D to create a game with words.
I have a big database of all the words that exist (700k words) and I just want to check if a word exist in the database.

Here is my query `SELECT Word FROM Words WHERE Word = 'IA' COLLATE NOCASE`
This take approximatly 0.3599885 sec to execute 
Is it possible to low down the time of the request ?

Comment: That seems pretty fast.  I'm guessing you already have an index on `word`.  If not, you can add one, remove the `collate` and see if that is faster.

Comment: Yes I have an index for all word. I store the words in lower normally so I tried LOWER and it works. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

OK I just found that `COLLATE NOCASE` is really slow.
I just used `LOWER()` Instead
The query take 0.0009974 sec now

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all words are stored in the table in **all lower case** (or all upper case for the matter). You can use a `CONSTRAINT` to ensure this. Then you don't need to use a collation to find the words, and that will make it blazing fast.

For example:

```
create table words (
  word varchar(50)
);

insert into words (word) values ('chicago'); -- always lower case
insert into words (word) values ('ia');
insert into words (word) values ('london');
```

Then create an index on the column:

```
create index ix1 on words (word);
```

Now, you can search fast:

```
select word from words where word = lower('IA');
```

**Note**: Here note the `LOWER()` function is applied to the "right side" of the equation (the value). If you apply it to the column, you'll make the query slow since you'll prevent the use of the index.